# Tool to find CPU utilization for a particular query in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I just want to know is there any free tool to identify CPU utilization for a particular query in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Why have you asked this question once again?  Have you checked my comment on the other one (which, incidentally, overlaps with @a_horse_with_no_name's answer below...)?

Comment: You may be interested in [pg_top](http://ptop.projects.pgfoundry.org/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CPU monitor of your operating system (e.g. `top` in Linux or ProcessExplorer in Windows).

Each connection to the database will create a new process on the server. The process id related to the connection is reported in the column `pid` of the system view `pg_stat_activity`.

With that process ID you can monitor the CPU usage of that process which is essentially the CPU usage of your query (while it's running of course)

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring.html  and the Postgres Wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Analysis_Tools